# Python AuthenticationError: gdax Invalid API Key

Tags: python, api, gdax-api

I was trying to trade and get balance from gdax. It requires me to specify the ApiKey、Secret、Password. However, when I created ApiKey recently on coinbase, they donot have an option to create the passphrase. So If I donot specify the password in my code, it would said "error: gdax requires `password`". If I specify 'password' as my login password, it world said "error: gdax Invalid API Key.". Their customer service is not being helpful. Anyone knows how to solve this?[When I create a new APIKey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6yY4.png)

Answer (score 0):

GADX (recently changed to Coinbase PRO) has different api authentication detail than Coinbase itself.
Coinbase's api allows you to manipulate coinbase wallet and make transactions on coinbase.
While GDAX's allows you to do stuff on GDAX (Coinbase PRO) you must have generated keys for regular Coinbase wallet, instead of GDAX/coinbase PRO